# Xcode will not let me use `@ObservedObject` on an optional

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a `ObservableObject` class called `MyObjectModel` that is passed to a struct like this:

```
var body: some View {
  MyView(myObjectModel)
```

But on another context I do not have a model to pass, so I want to call `MyView` simply as

```
var body: some View {
  MyView()
```

So I thought I could initialize `MyView` like

```
struct MyView: View {

  @ObservedObject private var model: MyObjectModel?

  init(model: MyObjectModel? = nil) {
    self.model = model
  }
```

But Xcode will not let me use `@ObservedObject` on an optional.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `ObservedObject` wrapper does not have constructor with optional for now (and we cannot extend `Optional` with conformance to `ObservableObject`, because it is not a class).

A possible approach is to have some specific mark that there is no model, as it would be nil.

Here is a demo:

```
class MyObjectModel: ObservableObject {
    static let None = MyObjectModel()     // Like NSNull.null
}

struct MyView: View {

    @ObservedObject private var model: MyObjectModel

    init(model: MyObjectModel? = nil) {
        self.model = model ?? MyObjectModel.None
    }

    var body: some View {
        if self.model === MyObjectModel.None {
            Text("Same as it would be nil!")      // << here !!
        } else {
            Text("For real model")
        }
    }
}
```